# Why is my loop not checking the argv for alphabets and printing out for an Error?

Tags: c, cs50

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFg8x.png)My program takes in Command Line arguments from user and checks to see:

- if Argc is less than 3 and more than 1
- whether each element of Argv stored in array is a digit or not

For Argv[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx447.png) which is stored as a string, if there are any **alphabets** or "symbols" , the program will output "Usage: ./caesar key".

For example if Command Line argument is:

"./caesar 20",  then the program will print out success

However, if its " ./caesar 20x" the program will output "Usage: ./caesar key".

But my program prints "Success" when I input "./caesar 20x"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx447.png)

My code whole code is as follows:

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1 && argc< 3)
    {
       printf("Success\n");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }

    for( int i=0; i < argc ; i++ )// Loop to check each element of the Array
    {
         if ( isalpha(argv [1][i] ) )// Function to check if each character is a digit or not
         {
                printf("Success\n");
         }
         else
         {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to format a question. As it stands here, the question is very hard to read, and nobody would like to anser questinos that are hard to read. Someone has done it for you, but please keep it in mind for your next question.

Comment: That edit needs an extra `}` to mark the end of `main`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to Stack Overflow and thus learning

Comment: What happens once `printf("Success\n");` has been done and what _should_ happen then?. Same question for `printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");`

Comment: @Jabberwocky, it's their first question, it's not a big deal. I'm sure' they're figuring it out.

Comment: `isalpha(argv[1][i])` Your loop goes until `i==argc`. You mix the length of `argv[1]` with the number of arguments. The loop should use condition `i<strlen(argv[1])`.

Answer (score 3):

For starters this condition

```
if (argc > 1 && argc< 3)
```

simpler to rewrite like

```
if ( argc ==  2 )
```

This loop

```
for( int i=0; i < argc ; i++ )
```

does not make sense. You need to travers the string pointed to by the pointer `argv[1]`.

Within the loop you are using the function `isalpha` As a result for each character of the string `"20x"` the function will return logical true.

Substitute the loop for the following loop

```
char *p = argv[1];

while ( *p && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

if ( *p == '\0' )
{
    printf("Success\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
}
```

Though it would be better to use the standard function `strtol` instead of such a loop.